# ayuda con una validacion

Tags: c#, validación

tengo esta validacion que deberia aceptar codigos de este tipo **AA4098765** (letras y numeros) pero no me esta validando la parte las letras.
La idea es que el codigo sea de letras y numeros y que si el usuario ingresa solo numeros que muestre el mensaje de error. Alguna sugerencia?

Codigo:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]*[1-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Formato de código incorrecto")]
```

Comment: Hola, es el 'codigo' arriba un parte de mensaje de error? Puede anadir el codigo C# mas completa por favor? El `regex`, `match`, o `pattern`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que el valor sea:

> ```
>   2 Letras mayusculas, Seguidas de 
>   7 Numeros
> ```

Esta seria una expresion regular que hace match:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}", ErrorMessage = "Formato de código incorrecto")]
```